# Visual studio error connecting exchange email account

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365, office-js, office-addins

About two months ago I was given the task of making a outlook.com add-in. The basics worked perfectly but somthing with higher priorety came along. So the project layed still fit the last two months.

I wanted to go on with the project yesterday and it didn't work anymore. The problem comes whem I go to  start the project in visual studio and, need to sign in to my office account. If I sign in it will load for a while and then an error pops up. It says:

```
An error occurred while connecting to the server: 

   The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server
```

How is this possible since i didn't change anything in the last two months?
And how can I fix the problem?

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio) from microsoft it self.

**Edit:**

Here are some screenschots:

[image: Start]

This is inside my Visual Studio, here I start my add-in. The following pop-up shows up. I have double checked my credentials.
[image: Popup]

If i click on connect it will load for a while and following error shows up:
[image: Error]

Hopes this gives some more information about what is going on.

Comment: This seems to be error related to "Office Account" and "Visual Studio" and not related to outlook addin. Can you post screenshot of "Visual Studio" from where you are trying to login?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have added some images.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the properties window of the manifest node you need to set the `Use multi-factor auth` property to true.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but I've spent a lot of time figuring this out! :)