# Assistance finding manifest node and editing its properties using Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

First post, hope I don't screw this up too much.

I have been tasked with creating an Add-in for Outlook. I am following a tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio) and am at the stage where I've already edited several files and now need to test out what I've done by connecting to an exchange email account through Visual Studio. I put in my credentials and hit connect, but after the loading animation I receive an error: [Visual Studio Connection Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Q8B.png)

I have attempted carefully retyping my credentials several times and I am sure the problem does not lie there. While researching possible solutions I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036540/visual-studio-error-connecting-exchange-email-account). It seems we are both having the same error, but I am having trouble implementing the solution that was given since I have no experience with Visual Studio or Outlook Add-in programs. I've tried searching through the Solution Explorer with the properties window enabled but I can't seem to locate any files that have multi-factor properties that can be edited.

Could someone please provide a detailed explanation of how to find the "manifest node" and set the multi-factor authentication to true?

Please let me know if I need to provide any other information/images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widen the Solution Explorer window so you can see the full name of the two projects. They should have the same name except that one name ends in "Web". The "manifest node" is the other project.

[image]